# How to disable tab specific sound control in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio

As I noticed that youtube maximises the audio of the current tab and lowers it for other tabs which might run in the background. In principle, it is a great feature, but it gets annoying when I am jumping between multiple tabs as the voice adjustment do not keep up and sometimes it lowers the voice for other things like Hangout App which only produces a notification once a while.

If it is relevant I am using an HP laptop pavilion with windows 10 and up to date chrome browser.